# Is this a lack of sincerity and will I be punished?

Tags: quran, sin

So basically I started hifdh two years ago and so far I learned half the Quran alhamdulillah but the only reason I did it was so that people would see how pious and good I was but just recently i started doing it purely for the sake of Allah. Will all my work be for nothing or will it still be rewarded?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but since you are doing it for the sake of Allah you are getting rewarded and let me tell you this every letter is one good deed remember this if you haven't so you are getting a lot of good deeds just dont let your past haunt you focus on now. Allah knows best